# Different field instances in class and parent/Call super constructor with method

Tags: scala

I am trying to call the super constructor from a class using a method. The whole setup looks like this:

```
class Straight(hand: Hand) extends Combination(Straight.makeHandAceLowIfNeeded(hand), 5)

object Straight {
  private def makeHandAceLowIfNeeded(hand: Hand): Hand = {
    ...
  }
}
```

While this does compile, it has some rather odd runtime behaviour. While debugging, I noticed that the Straight instances have the "hand" property defined twice. Can somebody tell me what is going on, and what the proper way is to call the super constructor with different arguments?
In my use case, I want to call the super constructor with a modified hand in which I replaced a card compared to the original constructor argument.

Debugger screenshot with duplicate field:
[image: [1]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a perfectly fine way to call the superclass constructor. These are two private fields and they don't conflict, though you can rename one of them to avoid confusion during debugging (or if you want to access the superclass' value from the subclass). However, the field should only be generated for a class parameter if it's used outside a constructor, and in your case it doesn't appear to be. Did you simplify the definition of `Straight`?

Comment: Yes, I indeed omitted a part. Thats quite an unexpected behavior, is there any resource which mentions this? Everything works as intended if I rename the sub-class constructor argument, but then I end up storing the argument the value in a field(which is never used). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: As I've said, the subclass constructor parameter should only become a field if it's actually needed outside the constructor. If you include the code for the subclass I expect it _is_ actually used. Otherwise this is probably a minor Scala bug.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I confused a few things. For example I thought that the compiler generates fields for all constructor parameters. But iirc this is only true for case classes. Debugging verified that no field is generated when I rename the constructor argument, and use the field(named hand) from the super class in my method.

Comment: "I thought that the compiler generates fields for all constructor parameters. But iirc this is only true for case classes." Not quite. It generates fields for parameters marked as `val` or `var` (and case class fields have `val` automatically) or, as already mentioned, if the parameter is used outside the constructor (in method or lazy val definitions).